# PHP/MySQL Have some rows in SELECT result have different values for a particular column when sorting

Tags: php, mysql

Right sorry for the complicated title wasn't sure how to best explain.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM uc_posts WHERE `postinguser` = 5 AND `id` NOT IN (SELECT dwable FROM uc_redwables WHERE redwabledby = 5) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM uc_posts WHERE id IN (SELECT dwable FROM uc_redwables WHERE redwabledby = 5) 
ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 20
```

The table `uc_posts` looks like this:

```
id | postinguser | time                | message |
1        5         2016-08-08 23:50:45      *
2        5         2016-08-08 23:50:35      *
3        5         2016-08-08 23:50:25      *
4        5         2016-08-08 23:50:15      *
```

The table `uc_redwables` looks like this:

```
id | dwable | redwabledby | time                | 
1      3          5         2016-08-08 23:51:15
```

The output looks like this:

```
   id | postinguser | time                | message |
1        5            2016-08-08 23:50:45      *
2        5            2016-08-08 23:50:35      *
3        5            2016-08-08 23:50:25      *
4        5            2016-08-08 23:50:15      *
```

I'm trying to find a way to substitute the time in the selected row(s) from the `uc_redwables` table and sort the corresponding row with it (without actually updating that row in `uc_posts`).

So that it would look like this:

```
   id | postinguser | time                | message |
3        5            2016-08-08 23:51:15      *     //time changed   
1        5            2016-08-08 23:50:45      *
2        5            2016-08-08 23:50:35      *
4        5            2016-08-08 23:50:15      *
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: instead of `select *` list certain fields, preceded by `tablename.` where that's the tablename the field is from. Except now you have to in some way `join uc_redwables` to your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
 p.`id` as id, 
 p.`postinguser` as postinguser,
 p.`message` as message,
 case r.dwable
  when p.id then r.`time`
  else p.`time`
  end as date_time 
FROM `uc_posts` p left join `uc_redwables` r on p.id = r.dwable
WHERE p.`postinguser` = 5 
AND r.redwabledby = 5 
order by date_time desc;
```

This should produce an output like:

```
   id | postinguser | date_time                | message |
3        5            2016-08-08 23:51:15      *      
1        5            2016-08-08 23:50:45      *
2        5            2016-08-08 23:50:35      *
4        5            2016-08-08 23:50:15      *
```

Comment: I tried running it but it still gives me the date_time 2016-08-08 23:50:25 for id 3. Other than that displays as shown before.

Comment: My bad, I thought you were matching the ids of the two tables. Just edited, should work now

Comment: Still not working :( Yes it's kind of complicated. It's basically list all rows from `uc_posts` where the `postinguser` is 5 AND list all corresponding rows from `uc_redwables` where the `redwabledby` is 5 whilst removing the duplicate and sorting the `uc_redwables` row by it's time. It's a retweet like function. I should add that the tables aren't exactly structured the same as each other (there are additional columns in different orders, I simplified it for the question). Would this effect the join?

Comment: To confirm `dwable` stores the corresponding `uc_posts` id.

Comment: Sorry again, I forgot to change `on p.id = r.id` to `on p.id = r.dwable`. I tested the query with  exact same data as yours. Will work this time for sure.

Comment: Hi @user3360140 I just realised that this just links when the dwable and the id are the same. That's fine but it should be only after it's confirmed that the redwabledby column is 5.

Comment: you can add another condition in the where clause `and r.redwabledby = 5`, Im updating my post hold on a while.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120530/discussion-between-user3360140-and-ben).